# How does scintillation work?

Tags: particle-detectors, gamma-rays

We are doing an experiment on [gamma spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_spectroscopy) and came across the concept of [scintillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scintillation_(physics)). It says that it's a property of materials through which we can change high energy photons (gamma photons in our case) into low energy photons.

I'm trying to understand how this mechanism works. Why is NaI(Tl) used for this purpose?

I read several Wikipedia articles and  [this text](https://web.stanford.edu/group/scintillators/scintillators.html). I can understand that high energy photons can have pair production and then there is a sort of cascading that can occur (but that I don't understand very well). I'm not sure how this produces these low-energy photons.

Can anyone help me understand how this mechanism takes place?

---

Let me be more specific:

First, The [article](https://www.dynasil.com/radiation-detection/what-are-scintillators-how-do-they-work/) that is posted in the comment doesn't talk, How does a single high -photon produces a large number of photons of small energy. While in this article, it's clear that some sort of cascade effect that I don't understand. Also it doesn't mention anywhere why, NaI is used. If it's doping that produces light then why we use NaI, why not something else.

Comment: Googling "how do scintillators work" brings up a variety of good suggestions.

Comment: @JonCuster No, that doesn't give my answer. And I have found any reasonable explanation by googling that is why I have put the question here.

Comment: https://www.dynasil.com/radiation-detection/what-are-scintillators-how-do-they-work/ is the top suggestion. Where are you running into issues?

Comment: The links provided are pretty clear.  Perhaps you need to reword your question to identify the specific step in the scintillation process that you don't understand.   Reradiation is always related to electrons dropping from a high energy level to a lower one.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I did that.

Comment: You might find [my answer to a question about the Compton edge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/378678/81133) helpful.